# IPV6 Dynamic DNS (cgnat/teredo)

Tags: ipv6, dynamic-dns, teredo

I'm trying to set up Dynamic DNS so that I can have an app hosted out of my house.

I have internet through Bell Canada and port forwarding/DMZ on the router don't seem to work (Checked with both nginx and netcat). From what I understand they are now using cgnat (Carrier Grade Nat) to translate IPV6 addresses into IPV4.

Does anyone know how to set up Dynamic DNS in this configuration? Or if its possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ISP uses CGN (i.e. NAT444, DS-Lite or NAT64/DNS64) then you don't have your own IPv4 address so you won't be able to host your own server.

If your ISP provides IPv6 (they really should, certainly if they deploy CGN) then you could run your server on IPv6. You should get a stable IPv6 prefix so you wouldn't need Dynamic DNS for that, just normal DNS would be fine. The downside is that your users will need IPv6 as well and not all ISPs support IPv6 yet so your server will not be reachable by everybody.

Situations like this are exactly the reason why people have been pushing for IPv6 support everywhere. Without it you will run into situations like this more and more, as all IPv4 addresses are allocated and ISPs just don't have enough to give a separate address to each customer. Unfortunately many ISPs are too late with their IPv6 deployment.

IPv6 should have been globally deployed ***before*** we ran out of IPv4 addresses. Now we ended up in a hole where IPv4 is no longer available and IPv6 is not yet fully deployed. Until IPv6 is available to everyone things like hosting your own servers often just isn't possible anymore...

Comment: Is it particularly hard to host on IPV6? And this is just a hobby application so I don't want to pay for a normal domain for DNS. Just adding a host file entry on my machine and a few others should take care of resolving the IPv6 address for my purposes. What other 'gotchas' are involved with this?

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: The only differences in "hosting on IPv6" are that the program must support IPv6 (some old ones still don't) and that your clients must, naturally, also have IPv6 access. (Unless you host on both v4 and v6, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: IPv6 is mostly "the same as IPv4 but with bigger addresses" for most applications. Under the hood there are lots of technical differences, but for a simple home server that shouldn't make much of a difference. The biggest difference is the absence of NAT, so instead of a port-forwarding you just open up the firewall for the server's address and ports. Much cleaner and easier to understand than al that mangling of packets that NAT does :)

Comment: That sounds alot easier I guess, does anyone know of a good port forwarding service for IPv6?

Comment: There is no port forwarding with IPv6 because there is no NAT with IPv6. See the previous comment: "so instead of a port-forwarding you just open up the firewall"